# Android: not getting access token with using my app on Twitter?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have integrate the twitter in my App with the help of [`this app`](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-send-image-to-twitpic-from-android/)

Now, I am able to do post. but Now i want it to works for my app. So i have changed the twitter_consumer_key and the twitter_secret_key with my app's Keys. And then have try but it gives me error message like below:

```
03-29 15:11:50.009: DEBUG/TwitterApp(880): Failed to get request token
03-29 15:11:50.009: WARN/System.err(880): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token
03-29 15:11:50.039: WARN/System.err(880):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
03-29 15:11:50.039: WARN/System.err(880):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
03-29 15:11:50.039: WARN/System.err(880):     at com.example.demo.TwitterApp$2.run(TwitterApp.java:119)
03-29 15:11:50.039: WARN/System.err(880): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token
03-29 15:11:50.049: WARN/System.err(880):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
03-29 15:11:50.049: WARN/System.err(880):     at oauth.signpost.basic.HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.getContent(HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.java:18)
03-29 15:11:50.059: WARN/System.err(880):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:228)
03-29 15:11:50.059: WARN/System.err(880):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:189)
03-29 15:11:50.059: WARN/System.err(880):     ... 2 more
03-29 15:11:50.139: WARN/InputManagerService(60): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@450b8428
```

Now, whats falt in my app ? All works great but not able to post the photo on twitter...

Please help me for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide some source code

Comment: @Dharmendra: i have give the link of the readyMade project. Just tell me if i change the consumer key and secrate and run the app as per my Twitter app then why it is not running ?

Comment: Have you generate the access token from the twitter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just got the Solution of my Problem.

Actualy I havent add the callback url to the app on Twitter. That's why i am not getting the Permition Window.

Now i have added the url like `http://someurl.com` and now my problem solved.

Thanks for the reply and comments.